# Reference when measuring the speed of fast moving objects

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

Let's assume an object is moving at a speed of V=50% of the speed of light, so the time in the frame of this moving object becomes slower by an amount of X.

when we say time becomes slower by, it becomes slower than what?
And when we measure the speed V, we measure it with respect to what?

Comment: Relative to the observer.

Comment: The time interval between two events is greater for the object in motion **acording to the stationary one**.

Answer (score 0):

The time becomes slower relative to the time that elapses for a stationary observer. Likewise, the velocity is measured relative to the frame of the stationary observer.